# If $f$ measurable and $f=g$ a.e implies $g$ measurable, then $\mu$ is a complete measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is easy to show that if $\mu$ is a complete measure, then $f$ measurable and $f=g$ a.e implies that $g$ is measurable.

However, is it true that if this implication holds, that is $f$ measurable and $f=g$ a.e implies $g$ measurable, then $\mu$ must be complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a $\mu$-null set, $E \subset N$, $f = 0$ and $g = \chi_E$.

Comment: Thanks. I was fixated on trying to take $f$ to be the identity, and that didn't seem to go anywhere.